# BottomNavigationView menu text not appearing

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview, android-menu

So I am trying to use BottomNavigationView in an activity.
When I see it in Design tab in Intellij I only see one of the items in menu and the other 3 are not visible.

Is this a problem in my build.gradle file?

main_menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Home"/>

    <item android:title="Test2"/>

    <item android:title="Test3"/>

    <item android:title=:Test4"/>

</menu>
```

XML for the activity:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                       android:id="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24" android:layout_gravity="end"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is what its looking like:
[image]

Also, I see "Path.op() not supported" Render Problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For show all items, you can use at the below code.

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

Comment: Could you share library versions you used?

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was the name of my menu file.

Answer (score 0):

Brother I got this error today, I couldn't fix it either, ran the project ( Run() ) it works, it's just not visible in the XML, it works)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877094)